# ¿Cómo eliminar strings dentro de un div sin borrar su contenido?

Tags: javascript, jquery, string

Buen día amigos, ¿cómo puedo eliminar el texto **"Esto debo eliminar"** sin borrar el div con id **"noBorrar"** con Jquery?

PD: no me sirve ponerlo dentro de una etiqueta HTML y luego llamarlo desde jquery.

Gracias de antemano.

```css
#noBorrar{
  
  border: 1px solid blue;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  margin-left: 5px;

}

#contenedor{

  border: 1px solid green;
  height: 100px;
  

}
```

```html
<div id="contenedor">
  &nbsp;Esto debo eliminar
  <div id="noBorrar">
     No eliminar esto
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Al seleccionar el array de Jquery te da el elemento de javascript, esto permite tomar el outerHTML, y asignarle después de limpiar.

```js
let noBorrar = $("#noBorrar")[0].outerHTML
$("#contenedor").html("");
$("#contenedor").html(noBorrar);
```

```css
#noBorrar{
  
  border: 1px solid blue;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  margin-left: 5px;

}

#contenedor{

  border: 1px solid green;
  height: 100px;
  

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="contenedor">
  &nbsp;Esto debo eliminar
  <div id="noBorrar">
     No eliminar esto
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! Esto era justo lo que necesitaba

Answer (score 3):

Puedes buscar el nodo texto (es el nodo cuyo `nodeType` es 3) y eliminarlo

```js
$('#contenedor').contents().filter(function(){
    return this.nodeType === 3;
}).remove();
```

```css
#noBorrar{
  
  border: 1px solid blue;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  margin-left: 5px;

}

#contenedor{

  border: 1px solid green;
  height: 100px;
  

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="contenedor">
&nbsp;Esto debo eliminar
  &nbsp;Esto debo eliminar
  <div id="noBorrar">
     No eliminar esto
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Se puede separar en dos partes el contenido HTML de `contenedor`, y dejar lo que se encuentre luego del caracter `<`.

Nota: Esto requiere volver a asignar todos los nodos que tenga dentro.

Código:

```js
var contenedor=$("#contenedor")
contenedor.html("<"+contenedor.html().split("<")[1])
```

```css
#noBorrar{
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
#contenedor{
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="contenedor">
  &nbsp;Esto debo eliminar
  <div id="noBorrar">
     No eliminar esto
  </div>
</div>
```